# How to get button value on dropdown change using ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I m facing a issue related to the requirement [![Refer][1]][1]

here if u see in the above pic i am dynamically loading the drop down and for that below is the code

```
<ion-label>Location</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="location" hidden  #sectionSelect [(ngModel)]="location" (ionChange)="onChange(sectionSelect.text)" >
            <ion-option *ngFor="let opt of allowedLocations" [value]="opt.LocationId">{{opt.LocationName}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
```

after this i am defining some values as Day,Week,Month,Custom based on the selection that particular result will be displayed

below is the code for Day,Month,Year,Custom i have created using  segment

**html code**

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="reportType">
      <ion-segment-button color="danger"  *ngFor="let opt of reportTypes" [value]="opt.TypeId" (click)="getData(location,reportType,'Header')">
        {{opt.Type}}
      </ion-segment-button>

    </ion-segment>
```

**Type Script Code**

```
 this.reportTypes=[{TypeId:1,Type:'Day'},{TypeId:7,Type:'Week'},{TypeId:30,Type:'Month'},{TypeId:10,Type:'Custom'}]
```

This works fine till now but here i m facing issue when ever i select a location i have to press again Day suppose if i select location B again i have to press Day instead of that on Dropdown selection can i trigger the method so that if i select **Day**  if i choose location A first then it has to location A , suppose if have i choose location directly after choosing it it has to display B day wise report and it has to take the day,week,month values ,so that by that only the report is generated day wise ,week wise, month wise

Comment: Please post your component code.